# Notation for the subobject classifier

Tags: ct.category-theory, notation

Does anyone know why in books on category theory the notation for the subobject classifier is almost everywhere the capital greek letter $\Omega$?
Gérard Lang

Comment: According to Mac Lane [_Concepts and categories in perspectives_], this was the notation used in "the initial IHES edition of SGA IV, where it is noted that the set $\Omega (X)$ of all subobjects of an object $X$ in a Grothendieck topos $\mathbb{E}$ defines a sheaf for the canonical topology on $\mathbb{E}$ and so, by Giraud's theorem, is representable by some object $\Omega$." That answers the question of where the convention originates, but not why...

Comment: Maybe it's from the case of sheaves on a topological space, where Ω is the sheaf of open subsets (i.e.,  Ω(U) is the set of open subsets of U). Open starts with the letter O, which in greek is Ω.

Comment: Maybe they had the christian 'alpha & omega' in mind. And the characteristic functions, as well as the true arrow end in omega. 